# Is there a hadith instructing Fatima to look after household affairs?

Tags: hadith, women, source-identification

If I'm not mistaken, Nabi SAW did say to Ali RA to look after the external affairs and Fatima RA to look after the household affairs. Am I right? If this was not said to them, to whom was this said? Because I did hear that as a hadith.

Can I get some references about this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is stated in a narration: Imam Ali (AS) and Hazrat Fatima (AS) arrived to divide the work in the presence of the Prophet of God and asked him to specify the duties of each in the affairs of the house. As Imam Baqir (AS) says, the Messenger of God (PBUH) also divided the work as follows: He ordered the Commander of the Faithful to do the work outside the house and also told his daughter Hazrat Fatima (PBUH) to manage the work inside the house and that Hazrat was happy with this division of labor

(Al-Humairi Qomi, 1413 AH, 52; Majlisi, 1363, 43: 81).
(Baharalanwar, vol. 43, p. 81, p. 1.)

https://www.ghbook.ir/index.php?name=%D8%A8%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B1%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AC%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%B9%D9%87%20%D9%84%D8%AF%D8%B1%D8%B1%20%D8%A7%D8%AE%D8%A8%D8%A7%D8%B1%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%A6%D9%85%D9%87%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%B7%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%B1%20%D8%B9%D9%84%D9%8A%D9%87%D9%85%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85%20%20%D8%AC%D9%84%D8%AF%2043&option=com_dbook&task=readonline&book_id=1000939043&page=81&chkhashk=AD453CD25A&Itemid=218&lang=fa&tmpl=component